# python remove special values from data set

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data set of movies.
I am using Pandas package.

In the variable "budget" (is an object type) there is often the "?" charachter.

Now I want to remove all movies, that contain a "?" in the budget variable.

In the end I want to convert the budget variable into a integer and run a regression with the variable "quality".
[Picture of the data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7abDu.jpg)
I have tried one method, but it doesn´t worked out.
while "?" in df.budget: df.remove(?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare for not equal (`!=`) `numpy array` created by `values` or convert all values to `string`s first and add [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for check all `True`s values per rows, last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcde?'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[4,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  4  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  ?  4  3  0  4  b

df = df[(df.values != '?').all(axis=1)]
#alternative
#df = df[(df.astype(str) != '?').all(axis=1)]
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  4  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.values != '?')
[[ True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True]
 [False  True  True  True  True  True]]

print ((df.values != '?').all(axis=1))
[ True  True  True  True  True False]
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcde?'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[4,3,5,7,1,'?'],
                   'E':['?',3,6,'?',2,4]}).astype(str)

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  a  4  7  4  ?
1  b  5  8  3  3
2  c  4  9  5  6
3  d  5  4  7  ?
4  e  5  2  1  2
5  ?  4  3  ?  4

#replace only in columns from list
cols = ['C','D','E']
#if only ? with numeric to NaNs
df[cols] = df[cols].replace('?', np.nan).astype(float)

#replace all non numeric to NaNs
#df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))

#replace NaNs by means
df = df.fillna(df.mean())
print (df)
   A  B    C    D     E
0  a  4  7.0  4.0  3.75
1  b  5  8.0  3.0  3.00
2  c  4  9.0  5.0  6.00
3  d  5  4.0  7.0  3.75
4  e  5  2.0  1.0  2.00
5  ?  4  3.0  4.0  4.00
```

Comment: Thank you for the demonstration! And which command should be used, if I want to replace the "?" with the mean() values of the columns?

Comment: @Christina - Do you need replace all columns by `mean`s? All columns are numeric?

Comment: The columns are "object" type.